# Save data from a gam plot without actually plotting the data?

Tags: r, mgcv

Is there a convenient way to extract the data from a gam plot, without actually plotting the gam object?

Here's a dummy example.  `plot.data` has the data I want in it, but I don't want the plot window to be affected.

```
library(mgcv)    
x=1:10000/1000
y = sin(x)+rnorm(10000,sd=2)
m = gam(y~s(x))
plot.data<-plot(m,plot=F)
```

Comment: which package `gam` belongs to? and `s` as well.

Comment: What "data" are you trying to extract exactly? Everything in `plot.data`?

Comment: `mgcv`.  edited for clarity

Comment: The data used to construct the plot.  I want to take that data, maybe do somethig with it, then add it to a different plot.

Comment: Just `names(summary(m))` and `names(m)` see what you want ant then just subset with `m$thing_you_want` or `summary(m)$thing_you_want`.

Comment: Did you actually run your code? `plot.data` doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Update your `mgcv`.  Older versions, it doesn't save the plot data. @HongOoi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like `plot.gam` has the option for not plotting.  But you could try

```
plot.data <- {
    dev.new()
    res <- plot(m)
    dev.off()
    res
}
```

or possibly

```
plot.data <- {
    pdf(NULL)
    res <- plot(m)
    invisible(dev.off())
    res
}
```

Comment: That's clever, if a bit hackish.  Thanks!

Comment: Gah!  This works, but if you've got it running inside of a loop (I am tryng to make some hackish animations), it hijacks your desktop environment such that it is a little hard to get back to the terminal and hit control-C!

Comment: @generic_user ok, try this updated hackery, using pdf null device

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `gam()` from the package `gam`, then you can get those data in list form by calling `preplot(m)`. Here's what that looks like for your data:

```
library(gam)
x = 1:10000/1000
y = sin(x)+rnorm(10000,sd=2)
m = gam(y~s(x))
preplot(m)

List of 1
 $ s(x):List of 5
  ..$ x   : num [1:10000] 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009 0.01 ...
  ..$ y   : Named num [1:10000] 0.421 0.421 0.421 0.421 0.421 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ se.y: Named num [1:10000] 0.0783 0.0782 0.0781 0.0781 0.078 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ xlab: chr "x"
  ..$ ylab: chr "s(x)"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "preplot.gam"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "preplot.gam"
```

The `x` and `y` components of that list are what I think you're after. Presumably, if you've got more than one smoothing term in your model, the ith component of the `preplot` list will correspond to the ith smoothing term in your original call to `gam()`.